# ScrollView in Android Studio while using a pull up refresh

Tags: java, android

So I have a refresh swipe down function, that when you pull from down anywhere on the screen it refreshes...However I don't want this,I have a listview, that is pumped by a JSon object..this part is not important, I got all of the json working...the part that I can't figure out is how to make it so when I pull up on the Listview i go up on the listview,right now when i pull up the whole page refreshes.
My XML for that page ...

```js
<in.srain.cube.views.ptr.PtrClassicFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ptr_care"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.fzhang.nhchecklist.ResidentCareActivity">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/care_summary_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/care_info_listview"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/care_summary_textview" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</in.srain.cube.views.ptr.PtrClassicFrameLayout>
```

My java

```js
  mPtrFrame=(PtrClassicFrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.ptr_care);
        mPtrFrame.setLastUpdateTimeRelateObject(this);
        mPtrFrame.setPtrHandler(new PtrHandler() {
            @Override
            public boolean checkCanDoRefresh(PtrFrameLayout frame, View content, View header) {
                return PtrDefaultHandler.checkContentCanBePulledDown(frame, content, header);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRefreshBegin(PtrFrameLayout frame) {
                updateDataWithPTR();

            }
        });
```

Anyone have any good ideas, there is also a refresh and onResume...Though that doesnt really matter (if it does please correct me) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

To achieve pull to refresh behavior that works on top of your list (it will work when you do a pull gesture on care_summary_textview) and not on list itself use this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.fzhang.nhchecklist.ResidentCareActivity">

   <in.srain.cube.views.ptr.PtrClassicFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ptr_care"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/care_summary_textview"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

   </in.srain.cube.views.ptr.PtrClassicFrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/care_info_listview"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ptr_care" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hey Ivan, thanks for the help, but now the listview doesnt appear at all, nor does the header that was attached the listview

Comment: Just to clarify, the refresh works, but the scrolling up on listview feature doesnt...thats what im trying to fix

Comment: Aha so you want to limit pull to refresh to work only when you pull from the top of the list, and not when you try to pull from any other view?

For my answer set proper constraints for your PtrClassicFrameLayout

Comment: Yes, if you pull the listview then move ONLY the listview, but if you pull above the top of the list, then refresh. Assuming my original XML works, how would I add constraints

Comment: Huh, it still does not work, this time, there is a textview, but no listview

Comment: can you add PtrClassicFrameLayout to your question please

Comment: Also I am aware it won't show up on that screen, because my JSON object isnt pumped while program isnt running....but yeah, when I run it on my S8 it does not show anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173181/discussion-between-ivan-milisavljevic-and-jewstin).